# How to make a partition of an external HDD drive that is bootable to ubuntu?

Tags: boot, multi-boot

I know this question has been asked many times, but the answers are frustrating. Read carefully before marking as duplicate.
My OS is Windows 10. 
I have a 1TB HDD (NTFS) external drive from which I actually made a 30 GB (exFAT) partition. Now I have a linux iso. And I want to make this 30 GB partition bootable with that linux iso.

**"Do it using unetbootin"**
unetbootin is not working as it cannot recognise neither the NTFS external drive, nor its exFAT partition.

**"Do it using rufus"**
rufus does recognise both the partitions of my external hard drive if I check the box that says "List USB Hard Drives" but it won't let me choose one of the two. The only choice it has is "Multiple Partitions" and it contains both the partitions. I cannot proceed with "format" while "Multiple Partitions" is selected, because I am not taking any chances.

Now, any help?